# Why does my negative button appear on the left side of my alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Do you want to continue?");
    builder.setMessage("Press Yes or No");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Positive button appears on right side instead of the left.

Comment: Well, you can just switch your "Yes" and "No" strings, the important thing is what is inside the listener of each button.

Comment: I think positive should be on right Side since its Positive .  Just switch the text and listeners .

Comment: Positive button appears in the right side only. It's the correct behavior

Answer (score 1):

By default AlertDialog put the positive button on the right (if you have a Left to right reading setting).
AlertDialog is impacted by reading direction settings so it will change based on the layout direction:

```
getWindows().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

If you want to swap the buttons what is suggested in the comment will work:

- swap string
- swap code

It will confuse the user though as they will expect the positive button to be on the right (for LtR readers)